# Can't see units on Boxplot in R

Tags: r, boxplot

R beginner here. When I try `boxplot(mtcars$mpg)`, I can't see any units on the bottom right where the plot is generated. How can I display units for the boxplot?

[image: Image of Graph]

Comment: If you want a single unit under the boxplot than you can do boxplot(mtcars$mpg,,xaxt='n');
axis(1, at=1, labels='unit')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boxplot(mtcars$mpg, las =2)    # las =1 will also do. (horizontal label)
```